# How to check if a value exists in a Google Sheet column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have successfully coded an app script in Google Site that makes a data entry into Google Sheet, but I made some alterations
index.html:

```
<div>
    <form id="email_subscribe">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="ادخل الاسم المقترح">
        <input type="submit" value="بحث">
    </form>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#email_subscribe" ).submit(function() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ret){
                $( "#thank_you" ).show("slow");
                $("#email_subscribe").slideUp();
                console.log(ret);
            }).checkName(this); //"this" is the form element
        });
    });

</script>
```

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
    .setTitle('Web App').setSandboxMode(HtmlService
    .SandboxMode.NATIVE);
    return html;
}

function checkName(form){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16-jpz1Xf-cbAshaIYMZpAkBflALw1YVu4m2hNHE-ZWQ/edit#gid=0').getSheetByName("names");
    var values = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(n=0;n<values.length;++n){
        var cell = values[n][0] ; // 1 is the index of the column starting from 0
        console.log(cell);
    }
}
```

The idea is that I want to make a simple system where the user wants to reserve a name, so first he checks if it is already reserved, then he proceeds to reserve it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I included a library called Arraylib that manipulates arrays 
this is how code.gs file works for me:

```
function doGet() {
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
.setTitle('Web App').setSandboxMode(HtmlService
.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
return html;
 }

function checkName(form){
var newName = form.namee;
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16-jpz1Xf-cbAshaIYMZpAkBflALw1YVu4m2hNHE-ZWQ/edit#gid=0').getSheetByName('names');
   var range = ss.getRange('A1:A');
   var reserved = range.getValues();
   var ind = ArrayLib.countif(reserved,newName);
if (ind == 0 ){
ss.appendRow([newName, user]);
 }
}
```